# MVC4 Doesn't pick up changes made to embedded JS/CSS files

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working on an existing project where the `Build Action` of Javascript and CSS files are set to `Embedded Resource`.

When i currently run the code then everything seems to look fine. But whenever i make a change to any of the CSS or JS files then it somehow doesn't recognize the change. Because it still uses the old code as if i didn't change a thing.

I checked FireBug to make sure i was editting the right CSS files, which was the case.

So i'm guessing the problem has something to do with the fact that it is set as an `Embedded Resource`. But i have no clue what to try next.

Anyone any idea why my changes aren't outputted to the browser? So, why it still uses the old code?

PS.

I did do a Clean / Rebuild All. But that didn't do the trick.

Comment: Are the responses that return these files to the browser being cached? Clear out your browser cache and see if you get the new version.

Comment: just add a querystring parameter to your js file to prevent browser caching like src='yourjsfile.jst?v=1'. So everytime you make any change to the js file, it will download latest from server, you don't need to clear browser cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your browser have stylesheets and js files cached. Just clean cache (you can to this by Ctrl + F5)

Comment: For some reason CTRL+F5 isn't doing the trick for me. That was one of the first things i've tried. So i tried Private Browsing now, which does the trick. So it's indeed browser caching. I'll just stick to Private Browsing then. Thanks for the advice.